# Delete a OneNote section using powerautomate

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-graph-onenote

Is there a way to delete a OneNote section using powerautomate? I checked the available methods in the OneNote connector and I also checked the graph api. I could not see a method to delete the section.
I can delete all the pages in the section and I would like to delete the section as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so its available. Being said that i remember the related [ask/uservoice/feature request](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Delete-a-page-in-OneNote-Action/idi-p/305227) regarding the same to be implemented.